# Displaying username data from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I want to display "username" from my firebase database to textView, but I get a null instead. I provide the image from myfirebase

[image]

```
private fun showUsername() {
    val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/users")
    ref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

        }

        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            val userName = p0.child("username").getValue().toString()
            txtUserTampil.text = userName
        }

    })
}
```

I expect to display the username to textView, but I get a "null" text. there is no error when I run this app

Comment: I think removing / before users will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are inserting users in something like the following way,

```
fun insertUser(user: User) {
    val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/users") 
    ref.push().setValue(user)
}
```

If that is the case, I would suggest you to keep the reference of the key to the user.

```
fun insertUser(user: User): String {
    val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/users") 
    val child = ref.push()
    child.setValue(user)
    return child.key
}
```

Now slightly modify your `showUsername()` so that it takes userKey as parameter which will take the exact reference of the user,

```
private fun showUsername(userKey: String) {
    val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/users")
    // Add listener to the specific user instead of whole users reference
    ref.child(userKey).addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

        }

        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            val userName = p0.child("username").getValue().toString()
            txtUserTampil.text = userName
        }

    })
}
```

Now call the above functions in the following way to store the key and/or pass it in the `showUsername()` function,

```
val user = User(...)
val userKey = insertUser(user) // store it
showUsername(userKey)
```

**Alternative**

If you are already storing uid and don't want to store userKey then I would suggest you to keep the uid out of the user's property and use it as the user's key,

```
val uid = ...
val name = ...
val email = ...
val user = User(name, email)
//Insert
val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/users")
ref.child(uid).setValue(user)
// Display
showUsername(uid)
```

Answer (score 1):

In firebase you cannot get reference of a child firstly you need to refer it's sub parent and then upon that reference you can call it's sub childs try this:

```
ref.child("you parent key").child("username").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        try {
            if (snapshot.getValue() != null) {
                try {
                    Log.e("TAG", "" + snapshot.getValue()); // your name values you will get here
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("TAG", " it's null.");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
        Log.e("onCancelled", " cancelled");
    }
});
```

Comment: Please consider providing a Kotlin version of the code sample you've provided instead of just pasting code from somewhere.

Comment: @Eric android studio supports automatic conversion just copy this code and paste it into kotlin class it will be automatically converted!!